# Original analysis results versus cross-validated results are dramatically different

Tags: cross-validation, multivariate-analysis, discriminant-analysis

I am using discriminant analysis to determine whether a company is likely to commit earnings fraud.  I have a 100% correct classification in the original analysis and a 46.7% correct classification in the cross-validation. (I'm using SPSS for the analysis. I'm using the "leave one out" option of cross-validation.)
Is the fact that the results are so different a problem?  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you should give more details, but sounds like overfitting.